# Plotting multiple recorded values in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Specialty, Recording 1, Recording 2, Recording 3
A,          100%,         200%,     300%
B,          50%,         -75%,      150%
C,          60%,          100%,    -25%
```

I would like to plot them on a graph so that it looks like this:
[image: text]

I believe I can do so with this:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=Recording 1, y=Specialty)) + geom_point()
```

How do I add Recording 2 and 3 to the same graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is example what the data looks like, I recreated it here for my answer.

Example data

```
structure(list(Specialty = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C"), class = "factor"), Recording.1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("100%", 
"50%", "60%"), class = "factor"), Recording.2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("-75%", "100%", "200%"), class = "factor"), 
    Recording.3 = structure(3:1, .Label = c("-25%", "150%", "300%"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

First, since the data has %'s you will need to remove that. `ggplot` needs numeric values to plot. NOTE: since you columns titles have spaces in them they need to be in

```
df$`Recording 1` <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df$`Recording 1`))
df$`Recording 2` <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df$`Recording 2`))
df$`Recording 3` <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df$`Recording 3`))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```

You can then use `reshape2` so you can plot everyone together.

```
df <- melt(df, id.vars='Specialty')
```

After that, you should be good to go to make the plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y=Specialty, fill=variable, color=variable)) + geom_point(stat='identity') + scale_x_continuous(name = "whatever (%)", limit = c(-100, 300))
```

or to add percent in the x-axis

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y=Specialty, fill=variable, color=variable)) + geom_point(stat='identity') + scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format(scale = 1), name = "whatever (%)", limit = c(-100, 300))
```

Here is the output

[image: example_update]

With percents in x-axis

[image: example_update2]

Comment: this looks really good, do you know how I set the values of my x axis though? Currently my graph looks like this: https://gyazo.com/1b5ba81e6a840cfa72662070978e481e

Comment: @Alex yeah sure, I edited my answer. You can change the values to whatever you want. I set the x-axis to -100 to 300

Comment: I got   could not find function "percent_format"

Comment: @Alex did you load `scales`? `library(scales)`

Comment: When I do I get Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: @Alex if you followed all the steps in my answer, you shouldn't get that error. I don't get that error

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, sorry for the back and forth

Comment: No problem. We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you an example data set. I've assumed you don't have the "%" in the dataset and the fields are numeric. We add the "%" to the x-axis label using the scales package. Point here is to first make your data long with pivot_longer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(Specialty = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Recording_1 = c(100, 50, 60),
                 Recording_2 = c(200, -75, 100),
                 Recording_3 = c(300, 150, -25))


df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = !Specialty, names_to = "Recording",
                    values_to = "Value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = Specialty)) +
        geom_point(aes(shape = Recording, color = Recording), size = 3)+
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+  #reverses A,B,C order
    scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format(scale = 1)) +
    theme_classic()
```

Here is what the output looks like.
[image]

Comment: even with the scale_x_continous then it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/1b5ba81e6a840cfa72662070978e481e

Do you know how to solve that?